# What is the answer to this riddle?

Tags: candy-box-2

In an ancient forest grows a very
old tree, on which live the most
intelligent animals in this world.
It is said that this tree has 60
roots, 360 branches and 2160 leaves.
How many marks can you find on its
trunk?

Answer (score 3):

How many marks can *you* see on the trunk?

> Hint: the squirrel is talking about the tree it is sitting in.

> Hint: Count the number of marks on the trunk on the page

> *Alright* the answer is 10.